# Files are not merging : python

Tags: python

I want to merge the contents of two files into one new output file .

I have read other threads about merging file contents and I tried several options but I only get one file in my output. Here's one of the  codes that I tried and I can't see anything wrong with it.

I only get one file in my output and even if I switch position of file1 and file2 in the list, i still only get only file1 in my output.

Here is my Code :

```
filenames = ['file1','file2']
with open('output.data', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

How can i do this ?

My whole code that leads to merging to these two files

```
source1 = open('A','r')
output = open('file1','w')
output.write(',yes.\n'.join(','.join(line) for line in source1.read().split('\n')))

source1 = open('B', 'r')
output = open('file2','w')
output.write(',no.\n'.join(','.join(line) for line in source2.read().split('\n')))

filenames = ['file1','file2']
with open('output.data', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: I assume that both files do actually contain something?

Comment: Your code is correct. Check that "file1" and "file2" exist and check their contents. Also check that you're examining the correct output file.

Comment: @aquavitae Otherwise he would not see even the contents of one of the files in the output?

Comment: @warunsl: I think aquavitae is trying to rule out the possibility that the second file is actually empty.

Comment: yes, they are very much exist and contain something. What I don't understand is why do I only get one file in my output . Both files do contain something (DNA sequences) . And I checked the correct output file.

Comment: the two inputs are actually outputs of another input files that i wrote in the same script. I should show the whole code and probably any mistakes could be detected :

Comment: Is there a chance you are reading from the file before you have flushed/closed it?

Comment: Is the fifth line really saying `source1`? Then `source2` in line 7 is undefined and hence `file2` will be empty.

Comment: after you've written your data to file: 1) write a newline 2) close file. See if it helps.

Comment: i'm sorry it should be source2 in the 5th line. I just changed the name here because the files I'm working with are confidential . Both file1 and file2 contain something when I opened them .

Comment: Why didn't you use `with` for the first two file operations? That's half your problem. The other is mixing source1 and source2

Comment: i added source1.close() after the first writing and another one source2.close() after the second writing. Still the same.

Comment: If you are on unix-like system, just do `cat file1 file2 > output.data`. Faster than python script I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit it's clear where your mistake is. You need to close (or flush) the file after writing, before it can be read by the same code.

```
source1 = open('A','r')
output = open('file1','w')
output.write(',yes.\n'.join(','.join(line) for line in source1.read().split('\n')))
output.close()

source2 = open('B', 'r')
output = open('file2','w')
output.write(',no.\n'.join(','.join(line) for line in source2.read().split('\n')))
output.close()

filenames = ['file1','file2']
with open('output.data', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

The reason why the first file is available is because you remove the reference to the file descriptor of `file1` by reassigning the variable `output` to hold the file descriptor for `file2`, and it will be closed automatically by Python.

As @gnibbler suggested, it's best to use `with` statements to avoid this kind of problem in the future. You should enclose the `source1`, `source2`, and `output` in a `with` statement, as you did for the last part.

Comment: also writing a newline before .close() is necessary, or last line of first file and first line of second file will be mangled.

Comment: @m.wasowski: I didn't know that. But from my testing, the code I posted works, although there is no final newline.

Comment: it works fine if files are ending with `'\n'` already. If they are not, there's a problem, because `'\n'.join` won't add newline after last element. Just as if you `cat` files.

Comment: It worked now.. I tried to close but apparently i closed the wrong file . Thank you so much.

Comment: From now on, please create the habit to use `with` statements, as suggested by @gnibbler

Answer (score 1):

The first file is being closed/flushed when you rebind `output` to a new file. This is the behaviour of CPython, but it's not good to rely on it

Use context managers to make sure that the files are flushed (and closed) properly before you try to read from them

```
with open('A','r') as source1, open('file1','w') as output:
    output.write(',yes.\n'.join(','.join(line) for line in source1.read().split('\n')))

with open('B','r') as source2, open('file2','w') as output:
    output.write(',no.\n'.join(','.join(line) for line in source2.read().split('\n')))

filenames = ['file1','file2']
with open('output.data', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            print("Reading from: " + fname)
            data = infile.read()
            print(len(data))
            outfile.write(data)
```

There is a fair bit of duplication in the first two blocks. Maybe you can use a function there.

Comment: Does this qualify as an answer? I would think that this should be in the comment section

Comment: @justhalf, it's a little hard to post code in a comment. I'll add to this answer as the OP provides more information

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine your read and writes into one with statement (if you don't really need the intermediary files); this will also solve your closing problem:

```
with open('A') as a, open('B') as b, open('out.txt','w') as out:
   for line in a:
       out.write(',yes.\n'.join(','.join(line)))
   for line in b:
       out.write(',no.\n'.join(','.join(line)))
```